# Modifying or injecting headers after fetching a git repo using FetchContent

Tags: c++, cmake, patch

Let's say one's importing a `cmake` project from a github repository via the `FetchContent` route. In order for the repo, in this case `hiberlite`, to play nice with my project, I need to inject/patch/replace one of its headers, say `hiberdefs.h` located in `${hiberlite_SOURCE_DIR}/include` with my own.

How does one do that such that my entire project only sees the modified header? Also, any libraries built by the repo must use the modified header.

##### `CMakeLists.txt`

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.24)

project(hiberlite_patch)

set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 20)

include(FetchContent)

FetchContent_Declare(hiberlite
        GIT_REPOSITORY https://github.com/paulftw/hiberlite
        GIT_TAG master
        )
FetchContent_MakeAvailable(hiberlite)

include_directories(${hiberlite_SOURCE_DIR}/include)

add_executable(${PROJECT_NAME} main.cpp)
target_link_libraries(${PROJECT_NAME} hiberlite)
```

Comment: `FetchContent_Declare` accepts parameter `PATCH_COMMAND` which is described in documentation for [ExternalProject](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/module/ExternalProject.html). In that parameter you could specify the command which will update the downloaded repo as you want.

Answer (score 4):

Thanks to @Tsyvarev 's comment above here's what one needs to do.

1. Obtain the `patch` file

```
git clone https://github.com/paulftw/hiberlite
cd hiberlite
# edit the repo as you see fit
git diff > hiberlite.patch
mv hiberlite.patch /path_to_your_project/patches/
```

2. Modify your `CMakeLists.txt` by adding `PATCH_COMMAND` to your `FetchContent_Declare`.

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.24)

project(hiberlite_patch)

set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 20)

include(FetchContent)

set(hiberlite_patch git apply ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/patches/hiberlite.patch)

FetchContent_Declare(hiberlite
        GIT_REPOSITORY https://github.com/paulftw/hiberlite
        GIT_TAG master
        PATCH_COMMAND ${hiberlite_patch}
        UPDATE_DISCONNECTED 1
        )
FetchContent_MakeAvailable(hiberlite)

include_directories(${hiberlite_SOURCE_DIR}/include)

add_executable(${PROJECT_NAME} main.cpp)
target_link_libraries(${PROJECT_NAME} hiberlite)
```

Comment: For anyone wondering, `UPDATE_DISCONNECTED 1` is the magic parameter (also from [ExternalProject](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/module/ExternalProject.html)) that's required to get it not to try to apply the patch again once hiberlite has been populated.  Without it, subsequent builds under the right conditions will fail when trying to apply the patch.